# Disaster Recovery: Deleted Entire Knowledge Base on Web (Zendesk)

Tags: google-chrome, caching, disaster-recovery

Running Chrome Version **96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)** under **Win10.**

Recently, through user error, we deleted apx. 100 articles from our customer knowledge base, which is hosted by Zendesk. Not one-at-a-time but by deleting the entire "brand" containing the info for our product.

It's uncertain, at best, if Zendesk will recover these valuable articles. So, I've been trying to find cached copies per the link below. I don't know enough about caching to understand if this "data" is stored on my hard drive, in the cloud, or both.

https://www.webnots.com/how-to-view-content-of-cached-page-when-it-is-not-accessible/

I've tried the above solutions (fortunately, I found some URLs from the deleted articles) but to no avail. In fact, options 6 and 7 did not work at all. And it would be nearly impossible to determine the article IDs (which are part of the article URLs) for 100 pages.

At this point, this process feels like a scavenger hunt: now and then I'll find a promising page or URL, but I've yet to find a complete article.

Perhaps I need to approach this problem from another angle? Can anyone offer some additional suggestions?  And if I'm lucky enough to find a usable copy of an article, how do I move it from the cache into a live web page?

Many thanks,

Steve

Comment: You might get a better answer on https://superuser.com instead.  Super User is a Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.